# Same address, but different content

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constants

I'm using a stringstream to get the content of a textfile (actually, it's a shader code source), in order to pass it to a function that take a const char* const* (glShaderSource). At first, I did that

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << input.rdbuf();

char const *code = buffer.str().c_str();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &code, 0);
```

It didn't work, for the reason that the content of *code* was not what was expected. Actually, if I'm doing this :

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << input.rdbuf();

char const *code = buffer.str().c_str();

printf("Code*: %p\n", code);
printf("Buff*: %p\n", buffer.str().c_str());

printf("Code0: %c\n", code[0]); // ERROR: prints garbage.
printf("Buff0: %c\n", buffer.str().c_str()[0]);

printf("Code1*: %p\n", &code[1]); // ERROR: prints garbage.
printf("Buff1*: %p\n", &buffer.str().c_str()[1]);

printf("Code1: %c\n", code[1]);
printf("Buff1: %c\n", buffer.str().c_str()[1]);
```

I get the same outputs for the pointer values, the correct outputs for the characters in the buffer, but random ones for the content of *code*.

Now, if I use a function like this :

```
void workaround(char const *code) {
    printf("Code*: %p\n", code);
    printf("Code: %s\n", code);
}

-------------------------------------

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << input.rdbuf();

workaround(buffer.str().c_str());

printf("Buff*: %p\n", buffer.str().c_str());
printf("Buff: %s\n", buffer.str().c_str());
```

I get the correct values for the pointers and the string contents.

Why does this code work and not the first one ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on funny/unexpected?

Comment: Could not duplicate: http://ideone.com/9G45jT

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, post it as an answer.

Comment: There's a correct answer posted by dreamlax but deleted for some reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem: the string returned by std::stringstream is temporary and is valid only until the end of the expression.

To expand the duration of validity of buffer.str(), it is possible to create a reference over the object. The life expectancy of the value will be extended to the one of the reference.

The following code works :

```
std::string const &string = buffer.str();
char const *code = string.c_str();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &code, 0);
```